# How to make a neural network with batches with different input shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to make a CNN or FCN that can take grayscale images as an input and outputs a color image. It is very important to me that the size of the images can vary. I heard that I can only do this when I make a FCN and take a batch with images of one size and another batch with images of another size. But I don't know how to make this concept in Tensorflow Keras (the Python version) and I was wondering if you could provide some sample code or pseudo code? I appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: Rescale all input images to have the same aspect ratio, width and height, distribution of values etc and then feed them to your model. Google `image preprocessing`.

Comment: But i don't want to downscale the images. I really need them to keep their original size

Comment: I'm not familiar with such approach, never heard of someone doing it. Try searching for related papers on `https://scholar.google.com`

Comment: Have you tried extracting patches and feeding only patches to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you want to keep them all in their original size, but that's not possible. Don't worry, though, because the resizing can take place while the images are being fed into the model (while in memory); the image will never be touched except to be read.

[Here's a great example](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) that I frequently reference!

Comment: You know, it is important to me that the output image is the same size as the original image. Is this really not possible?

Comment: Ah! No, not at all! The output image can definitely be the original size. Different architectures handle this differently, but consider this: Image gets resized, goes through the network, produces bounding box coords and class predictions. Those coords are then scaled to the original image size/ratio, and laid out on the original image (in its original size/ratio). Does that make sense?

Comment: But is this lossless?

Comment: So, to be clear here, image input into the network is a fixed size; the image must be resized on entry into the network. However, once its gone through the network for prediction, the coordinates can just be rescaled and laid on the original image.

Comment: Your original image is completely unchanged, so yes, it is lossless to the original image, minus whatever compression is involved in saving it again (once you have the classes/bounding boxes on it). The box might be off by a few pixels here or there, but that's going to happen anyway, since no network is perfect. Theoretically, you could save the predictions and bounding box coordinates separately, thus leaving the image completely untouched.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful!

Comment: Hey just to be more specific (since I forgot you'd been talking about grayscale to color images), that process is inherently lossy, but you could perform a less lossy version by saving the predictions separately (as mentioned before), and then apply them to the image without changing pixel luminosity. This means using the prediction's color values as weights for the original image's pixels, scaled so that the pixel luminosity sum (across all three channels) is unchanged. That doesn't need to be a network, though; just some math afterward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191964/discussion-between-stefan-and-thelonederanger).